# Função JQuery.load() não traz o elemento textarea com valor atualizado

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extensão

Bem, eu tenho uma extensão do chrome com página1 e página2, cada qual com seu script.js. Na página1 posso abrir uma nova guia/janela quando clico em um botaoX, sendo que quando a nova guia é aberta, o .html da página2 chama um script que busca, via JQuery.load(), carregar uma div com um elemento `<textarea>` da página1, só que acontece o seguinte: o `<textarea>` vem com o valor inicial do DOM quando carregado/construído, mas antes de clicar no botaoX da página1, o `<textarea>` foi editado - eu inseri um novo valor através de um script, no entanto, quando a funcao `.load` busca tal elemento da página1 para a página2, ele vem com o valor original.  O comando no script.js da página2 é o seguinte:

```
$("#divPagina2").load("../pagina1.html #idTextareaPagina1");
```

Resumindo: no .html da página1, eu defino `<textarea>` com valor `textareaOriginal`, depois, no script.js desta página1, eu atualizo para (por exemplo) `textareaComValorAlterado`, e justamente esse valor alterado não é levado pela .load(). Alguma dica?

Comment: O load faz uma requisição GET e devolve o valor inicial, para que seja pego o valor novo, o inicial deve ser trocado pelo novo ou ao alterar, o valor novo ser salvo em algum lugar, como o LocalStorage para ser acessado pela segunda página

Comment: O `.load` vai buscar o que tá no servidor, não o que está na tela do navegador.

Comment: Guilherme Constamilam... e como fazer isso, pode demonstrar? grato.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [sessionStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage). Ele cria um cookie temporário que só vale para aquela sessão da página (depois que fecha o site, o cookie é apagado pelo navegador).

Ao clicar no botão que abre a nova aba, execute isto antes do código que abre a nova aba:

```
var texto = $("#idTextareaPagina1").val(); // pega o conteúdo do textarea
sessionStorage.setItem("textarea", texto); // cria o cookie
```

Na página da nova aba, você pega o valor do `sessionStorage` e joga na div:

```
var texto = sessionStorage.getItem("textarea"); // pega o valor do cookie
$("#divPagina2").text(texto); // insere na div o conteúdo do cookie
```

> Observe que se o conteúdo do textarea tiver códigos HTML, troque o
>   método `.text()` por `.html()` na última linha acima.

Comment: Sam... valeu pela dica, embora tenha tentado com sessionStorage e não  ter dado certo, haja vista que este expediente é somente para trabalhar na mesma página/aba, por isso, troquei para o localStorage, e tudo certo!

Comment: session e local são a mesma coisa, a única diferença é que um é temporário e o outro é por tempo indefinido.