# Passar uma variável que está em um arquivo javascript para uma $_SESSION e pegar em uma página php

Tags: php, javascript, html, jquery, codeigniter

Bom noite amigos.

Seguinte estou precisando passar uma variável de um arquivo .js para uma Session e pra pegar em outra página com php. 
A função javascript retorna o primeiro horário disponível para marcação de uma consulta, e preciso deixar isso setado inicialmente em outra página.

```
var hr = now.getHours();
var min = now.getMinutes();
var time_format = hr + ":" + min;
//document.write ("<h3> Hoje Ã© " + hr + ":" + min + ". </h3>");
//$('#next_time').html('28 de dezembro (sexta-feira) - 14:00 horas');
var seconds = now.getTime() / 1000;
var doctor_id = $('#doctor_id').val();
var clinic_id = $('#clinic_id').val();
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: base_url+"Searchdoctor/doctor_availability?"+"date="+seconds+"&doctor_id="+$('#doctor_id').val()+"&offset=0&clinic_id="+$('#clinic_id').val(),
  success: function(result){
        if(result.data.time_interval.length>0)
        {
          $('#schedule-consult-timeslot').html('<option disabled selected>'+'Horarios disponiveis'+'</option>');
          $.each(result.data.time_interval, function (i, item) {
            if(item.length != 0){
                var split = item.time.split('-');
                if(compararHora(time_format,split[0])){
                   $('#next_time').html(now.getDate ()+ ' de '+ monName[now.getMonth()]+ ' ('+dayName[now.getDay()]+') '+ '- '+ split[0]+ ' horas');
                   return false;
                }
            }

          })
        }else{
           recursiveDate(1);
           //console.log( adicionarDiasData(3) );
        }
    },
    error: function(xhr, status, error) {
        var err = eval("(" + xhr.responseText + ")");
        alert(err.Message);
    }

  });

  function compararHora(hora1, hora2)
{
    hora1 = hora1.split(":");
    hora2 = hora2.split(":");

    var d = new Date();
    var data1 = new Date(d.getFullYear(), d.getMonth(), d.getDate(), hora1[0], hora1[1]);
    var data2 = new Date(d.getFullYear(), d.getMonth(), d.getDate(), hora2[0], hora2[1]);

    return data1 < data2;
}

function recursiveDate(cont){
    /*if(cont == 5){
        console.log('parou');
    }else{
        console.log(cont);
        cont = cont + 1;
        recursiveDate(cont);
    }*/
    var seconds = adicionarDiasData(cont);
    $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: base_url+"Searchdoctor/doctor_availability?"+"date="+seconds+"&doctor_id="+doctor_id+"&offset=0&clinic_id="+clinic_id,
      success: function(result){
            if(result.data.time_interval.length>0)
            {
              $('#schedule-consult-timeslot').html('<option disabled selected>'+'Horarios disponiveis'+'</option>');
              $.each(result.data.time_interval, function (i, item) {
                if(item.length != 0){
                    var split = item.time.split('-');
                       date = getDateFormat(cont);
                       $('#next_time').html(date.getDate ()+ ' de '+ monName[date.getMonth()]+ ' ('+dayName[date.getDay()]+') '+ '- '+ split[0]+ ' horas');
                       //colocar a session com todos os dados acima;
                       return false;
                }
              })
            }else{
              cont = cont + 1;
              recursiveDate(cont);
            }
        },
        error: function(xhr, status, error) {

            console.log(error);
        }

      });
}

function adicionarDiasData(dias){
  var hoje        = new Date();
  var dataVenc    = new Date(hoje.getTime() + (dias * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
  return dataVenc.getTime() / 1000;
  //return dataVenc.getDate() + "/" + (dataVenc.getMonth() + 1) + "/" + dataVenc.getFullYear();
}

function getDateFormat(dias){
  var hoje = new Date();
  return new Date(hoje.getTime() + (dias * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
}
```

o que eu estou precisando passar para uma SESSION é exatamente o que está dentro do id #next_time. Pois preciso pegar em outra página php.

ISSO -> 
date.getDate ()+ ' de '+ monName[date.getMonth()]+ ' ('+dayName[date.getDay()]+') '+ '- '+ split[0]+ ' horas');

Obrigado :)

Comment: Acredito que esse post possa te ajudar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35091757/parse-javascript-fetch-in-php basicamente é fazer um fetch no js passando no body a variavel e recuperando ela no php.

Comment: Talvez uma `sessionStorage` do próprio JS possa lhe atender. Veja nesta resposta como é simples criar uma e recuperar o valor: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/357226/8063

Answer (score 0):

O que eu faria é o seguinte...

```
if(compararHora(time_format,split[0])){
    var ndate = now.getDate ();
    var nmonth = monName[now.getMonth()];
    var nday = dayName[now.getDay()];
    var nhour = split[0];       

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST", 
        data: {ndate:ndate, nmonth:nmonth, nday:nday, nhour:nhour},
        url: BASE_URL + "Searchdoctor/set_date",
        success: function(data) {
            ('#next_time').html(now.getDate ()+ ' de '+ monName[now.getMonth()]+ ' ('+dayName[now.getDay()]+') '+ '- '+ split[0]+ ' horas');
        }
    }); 

    return false;
}
```

A função dentro do controller `Searchdoctor -> set_date`:

```
function set_date(){
    $set_date['ndate'] = ($this->input->post('ndate')) ? $this->input->post('ndate') : '';
    $set_date['nmonth'] = ($this->input->post('nmonth')) ? $this->input->post('nmonth') : '';
    $set_date['nday'] = ($this->input->post('nday')) ? $this->input->post('nday') : '';
    $set_date['nhour'] = ($this->input->post('ndate')) ? $this->input->post('nhour') : '';

    return $this->session->set_userdata('search_return', $set_date);
}
```

E para exibir, na sua view:

```
echo $this->session->userdata('search_return')->ndate . 'de' . $this->session->userdata('search_return')->nmonth . ' ' . $this->session->userdata('search_return')->nday . ' ' . $this->session->userdata('search_return')->nhour . 'horas';
```

Comment: Obrigado amigo, eu vou tentar fazer dessa forma e posto o resultado.